# Is this SQL query correct? First time using count

Tags: sql

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
WHERE COUNT(*) > value;
```

I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: And we have no way of knowing either.  We don't know what your data looks like.  We don't know what you are trying to do.  Sample data, desired results, a clear explanation, and a database tag would make for a much better question.

Answer (score 2):

When ever you are using aggregate functions like (sum, count, max, min) and you wanted to filter it out through the aggregate function, you have to use **having** clause instead of **where** clause.

Below is the query you are expecting.

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jim said correctly in his post. Also, if you want to add where clause then this is the query syntax:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
WHERE col1='SomeValue'
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > value;
```

Where clause will filter the data of the whole table here, before Group By clause. And then Group By clause will be applied on top of this filtered content, which could further be filtered by Having clause. Where clause does not accept aggregate functions like count(1).